# Subsequence and convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

Let $(a_n); n \in \mathbb{N}^+$ be a sequence such that $(a_{2k}), (a_{2k+1}), (a_{3k})$ with $k\in \mathbb{N}^+$ are convergent. Show that $(a_n); n \in \mathbb{N}^+$ is convergent.

Answer (score 3):

Assume that $a_{2k} \to x$, $a_{2k+1} \to y$, $a_{3k} \to z$. Then we have that:
$a_{6k} \in \{a_{2k}\}$ and $a_{6k} \in \{a_{3k}\}$. Therefore we must have that $x=z$, as $a_{6k}$ converges as a subsequence of a convergent sequence and it must converge to a unique limit. Similarly $a_{6k+3} \in \{a_{2k+1}\}$ and $a_{6k+3} \in \{a_{3k}\}$ and so $y=z$.

Now you have that the subsequence of even-indexed terms and the subsequence of odd-indexed terms converge to the same limit, so the sequence must converge to it. Indeed if they both converge to $L$ for given $\epsilon > 0$ we have that $\exists n_1 \in \mathbb{N}$ s.t. $n \ge n_1 \implies |a_{2n} - L| \le \epsilon$ and $\exists n_2 \in \mathbb{N}$ s.t. $n \ge n_2 \implies |a_{2n} - L| \le \epsilon$. Now choose $n_0= \max\{2n_1,2n_2\}$ Then you have that:

$$n \ge n_0 \implies |a_n - L| \le \epsilon$$

So $\{a_n\}$ is a convergent sequence.